# Is it required to use Unity for Playstation Mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playstation-portable

I'm trying to develop for Playstation Mobile on the PS Vita.

I searched for the Playstation Mobile Suite Developer assistant.

PSM for Unity is the only items that came up. As I don't want to use Unity, I tried to find just regular PSM.

Luckily I have an old download for PSM Suite so I used that.

Is it becoming a requirement to use Unity soon?

Answer (score 0):

Unity for PSM only offers an option to develop for PSVita (PSM for downloadable content) without having PSVita DevKit.

More information here:
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/04/08/playstationvita-for-all-the-unity-for-playstationmobile-public-preview/